# how to use very old iText(under 0.99) to create bookmarks / outlines?

Tags: pdf, itext, bookmarks, itextpdf

may I know how to use **old** iText(very old version under 0.99, package path = com.lowagie.xxx) to create bookmarks to jump in the internal pdf pls?

like the api in **new** iText jar:

```
PdfOutline outoline2 = com.itextpdf.pdf.PdfAction.gotoLocalPage("destinationName", false)
```

we have found below code to create bookmark, but find **old** iText needs to use the filename(see outFileName in below code). but what we want is a jump in internal pdf (not remote pdf)

```
olineSignature = new PdfOutline(root, new PdfAction(outFileName, "Signature2TxtDestination"), "Signature2TxtOutline");
```

FYI, we don't know what page number in advance, so no way to use the api as below: old PdfAction.gotoLocalPage(int, PdfDestination, PdfWriter)

anybody can help me? Thanks.@Bruno Lowagie, @itext :)
We are in the progress of upgrading to new iText(itext5+), but now we do get a request to create bookmarks(using old iText) for others to retrieve the created bookmarks.

Answer (score 1):

My memory can't go that far back but local destinations are most probably not supported. Your only chance is to do an interim upgrade to the Jurassic 2.1.7 that should be more or less compatible with that Pleistocene 0.99.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
we will not upgrade to 2.1.7 currently, and we are in the progress of upgrading to itext 5+.

Let us try to find another way to create bookmarks that can be used to internal jump without know out file name and page number in advance.